# The orientation of a sloped node in the presence of `allow upside down`

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) node[midway,sloped] {$y$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting image is

[image: A node on a line]

If we add `allow upside down` to the node's option list, the resulting image is

[image: The same node, upside-down]

Why did TikZ decide to orient the second `y` the way it did? Why isn't it oriented like the first one? After all, the option is called merely *allowed* upside down, not *required* upside down? Indeed, if the order of the coordinates is switched, the second `y` is oriented the same way as the first one.

What is the *rule* that TikZ uses to determine how to orient the `y`, so that, knowing it, I can predict in advance what the result will look like?

Comment: because your slope going down ... and in this case you enable to act option ` allow upside down`. for comparison try \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[midway,sloped] {$y$};`  with this option and see result: as expected :)

Comment: @Zarko: With the coordinates you suggested, the `y` is oriented the same way regardless of the presence of the `allow upside down` option. My question is: what is the *rule* that TikZ uses to decide how to orient the node in the presence of this option?

Comment: /tikz/allow upside down=<boolean> "If set to true, TikZ will not “righten” upside down text." (p.237 in tikz manual). You draw left up. Swap the coordinates: and draw`\draw (0,1) -- (1,0) node[midway,sloped,allow upside down] {$y$};` instead and everythink is like expected.

Comment: @Bobyandbob: This implies that in the case I presented the second image is the "right" one, whereas the first one is "rightened". Why is the second one the right one? Why isn't the first one the right one?

Comment: @EvanAad The default orientation is from left to right along the path...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Can you please write this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to `\pgftransformlineattime` in Section 103.2.2 for manual version TikZ v3.0.1a. Roughly explained the line case (curved case is similar):

First part is not related to this behavior which is the concept of timer 0 being the start point and 1 being the end point. So after some black magic the `pos=0.5` (from `midway`) is handled and we know where the point of node placement would be. If `sloped` is enabled then a simple `(x1-x0)` and `(y1-y0)` calculation is performed.

If `allow upside down` is enabled then `(x1-x0)` is checked. If the x-difference is negative the sign of the end point is flipped otherwise nothing happens and a normalized vector pointing to the end point is used and a coordinate transformation is set up. Then the node obeys that transformation.

For the interested here is the code version of the rough story above.

```
\def\pgftransformlineattime#1#2#3{%
  \pgf@process{#2}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@x% xb/yb = start point
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@process{#3}%
  \pgf@xc=\pgf@x% xc/yc = end point
  \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointlineattime{#1}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}}%
  \ifpgfresetnontranslationattime%
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations%
  \fi%
  \ifpgfslopedattime%
    \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgf@xb%
    \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgf@yb%
    \ifpgfallowupsidedownattime%
    \else%
      \ifdim\pgf@xc<0pt%   
        \pgf@xc=-\pgf@xc%
        \pgf@yc=-\pgf@yc%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xc%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yc%
    \pgfpointnormalised{}% x/y = normalised vector
    \pgf@ya=-\pgf@y%
    \pgftransformcm%
    {\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y}}%
    {\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \fi%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the edges of a generic rectangle, each edge of a non-empty textbox can be uniquely classified as either the left, the right, the top, or the bottom edge of the textbox, as naturally induced by the flow of the text contained in the textbox (assuming a single directionality text, as opposed to a text containing, say, both English and Hebrew).

[image: The edges of a textbox can be naturally classified as left, right, top or bottom.]

Non-degenerate line segments in TikZ are directed: they have a uniquely determined start point and a uniquely determined end point, and hence a uniquely determined direction, namely from the start point to the end point. Hence, a TikZ line segment naturally determines a vector.

[image: A TikZ line segment is a vector.]

When a node at the end of a line segment is `sloped`, its text runs parallel to the line segment: the top and bottom edges of the textbox encapsulated by the node are parallel to the line segment.

If additionally the `allow upside down` option is specified, the textbox is oriented such that the text's natural left-to-right flow (assuming a left-to-right language like English) occurs in the direction of the line segment. In other words, the vector determined by the line segment points from the textbox's left edge to the textbox's right edge.

[image: Orientation of a textbox in the presence of <code>allow upside down</code>]

If the `allow upside down` option isn't specified, the textbox is oriented such that the bottom of the text faces the bottom of the TikZ picture. Assuming that no explicit rotation was applied to either the TikZ picture or the node, this means that an imaginary ray emanating from the center of the textbox and crossing the bottom of the textbox at a right angle will also eventually cross the bottom edge of the page.

[image: Orientation of a textbox sans <code>allow upside down</code>]